# save two dimensional array in HSQLDB

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, hsqldb

please how can i save in data base two dimensional array in data base using hsqldb. i also try to save a HashMap> or Arraylist collections but it d'nt work.

public MyEntity {

String id;

double[][] data;

ArrayList arrayValue;

}

Comment: One possibility for a two dimensional array: make three columns; one for x index, one for y index, and one for the actual value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use your rows with your row IDs for the x index and then the columns would be the Y index. You need to dimension ahead of time and have the columns be column1, column2, column3, etc. You would probably wrapper the whole thing with a class that you access row column and hide the nastiness away from the client.